# Partition table invalid or corrupt

Tags: android, linux, android-build

I built Android 4.1.1 for Virtual Box and I'm using installer.vdi to install the Android OS to another hard disk. I'm booting from installer.vdi but I get the following error:

```
Error 5: Partition table invalid or corrupt
```

Do you have any idea why I get this error?

Answer (score 0):

The partition of the drive is corrupt. Reformat the partition and make sure you backup anything that might be on that partition if anything is still accessible.

Comment: What partition? I made the hdd in Virtual Box... what to format?